# Yii2 url manager parameter before controller

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing, yii-url-manager

I have a site where I want a different experience for each state, and need the url to be related to the city.  So instead of
mysite.com/site/login

it would be

mysite.com/utah/site/login
mysite.com/colorado/site/login
etc

And this would apply to all urls:

mysite.com/services/view/1 becomes
mysite.com/utah/services/view/1

mysites.com/customer/purchase-order/create becomes
mysites.com/coloroda/purchase-order/create

etc, etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use pattern

```
                Yii::createObject([
                    'class' => UrlRule::class,
                    'pattern' => '<city>/site/view<id:\d+>',
                    'route' => 'site/view',
                ]),
```

Where `city` and `id` are input parameters to the `actionView` in `SiteController`